# populating/retrieving a list<> of objects in a list using a setters getters

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm trying to learn how the lists work and I'm quite lost on a concept of using set; get; properties and working with a List. I have a project that I want to populate a list with 2 items that are related to each other (hence a object) Relation and an ID so I created a RelationLink class, the idea is to populate list with these 2 prosperities but using (get; set;) and I'm not quite sure how to do this so it would let me add the properties to a list and retrive a list from a PropertiesRepository as well.

```
 public class PropertiesRepository
{
    
    public class RelationLink
    {
        public string Relation { get; set; }
        public string LinkID { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListofRelations
    {
        public List<RelationLink> relList { get; set; }

        public void addRelation(RelationLink rel)
        {
            relList.Add(rel);
        }
    }
}
```

the code below fails at listofRelations.addRelation(relationLink) when debugging I can see that its going to add addRelation method and I see the values being passed. However when adding the object to a list nothing is being added. so when get runs it fails due to null exception.
am I doing the setters getters correctly? the part where I'm lost is how can I add the 2 (string) properties to that list in a main program file with setters, that could be read from relList

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        PropertiesRepository repProperties = new PropertiesRepository();
        PropertiesRepository.RelationLink relationLink = new PropertiesRepository.RelationLink();
        PropertiesRepository.ListofRelations listofRelations = new PropertiesRepository.ListofRelations();

        relationLink.Relation = "Relation A";
        relationLink.LinkID = "12345";

        listofRelations.addRelation(relationLink);
        foreach (var elm in listofRelations.relList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Relation from List is " + elm.Relation + "Link ID from List is " + elm.LinkID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`relList` in your instance of `listofRelations` is never initialised with an instance of the list.

```
public class ListofRelations
    {
        public List<RelationLink> relList { get; set; } = new List<RelationLink>();

        public void addRelation(RelationLink rel)
        {
            relList.Add(rel);
        }
    }
```

you could initialise it like this or in a constructor. Or before you call addRelation you could write if you want.

```
listOfRelations.relList = new List<RelationLink>();
```